# error 'No such file or directory: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/cytoolz/_version.py' when compiling a kivy app using web3.py, buildozer and colab

Tags: kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am trying to create a simple app to test connection to WEB3 with web3.py and kivy.

Here is my main.py :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from web3 import Web3

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
        web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
    
        if (web3.isConnected()):
            print("Connected!")
            return MDLabel(text="OK connected ! ", halign="center")
        else:
            print("KO")
            return MDLabel(text="KO ", halign="center")

MainApp().run()
```

and this is my requirements in buildozer.spec :

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = 
    python3,
    cython,
    kivy,
    kivymd,
    pillow,
    android,
    attrdict,
    certifi,
    cffi,
    chardet,
    cytoolz,
    eth-abi,
    eth-account,
    eth-accounts,
    eth-hash,
    eth-keyfile,
    eth-keys,
    eth-rlp,
    eth-utils,
    eth-typing,
    hexbytes,
    idna,
    lru-dict,
    openssl,
    pycryptodome,
    pyzbar,
    raven,
    requests,
    rlp,
    setuptools,
    toolz,
    web3
```

Compilation worked but when i run the app i have the following message with logcat :

```
08-22 08:36:31.065 16472 16505 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-22 08:36:31.066 16472 16505 I python  :    File "/home/HelloWeb3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
08-22 08:36:31.066 16472 16505 I python  :    File "/home/HelloWeb3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/helloweb3/arm64-v8a/web3/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
08-22 08:36:31.066 16472 16505 I python  :    File "/home/HelloWeb3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/helloweb3/arm64-v8a/eth_account/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
08-22 08:36:31.066 16472 16505 I python  :    File "/home/HelloWeb3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/helloweb3/arm64-v8a/eth_account/account.py", line 15, in <module>
08-22 08:36:31.066 16472 16505 I python  :    File "/home/HelloWeb3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/helloweb3/arm64-v8a/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
08-22 08:36:31.067 16472 16505 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/user/0/org.test.helloweb3/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cytoolz/itertoolz.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
08-22 08:36:31.067 16472 16505 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

So i made custom recipes to compile toolz and cytoolz:

toolz

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import CythonRecipe 


class ToolzRecipe(CythonRecipe): 
    """Build toolz"""

    version = "0.12.0"
    url = "https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/archive/refs/tags/{version}.zip"
    name = "toolz"

    depends = ["setuptools"]


recipe = ToolzRecipe()
```

cytoolz

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import CythonRecipe 


class CytoolzRecipe(CythonRecipe): 
    """Build cytoolz"""

    version = "0.12.0"
    url = "https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/archive/refs/tags/{version}.zip"
    name = "cytoolz"

    depends = ["setuptools"]


recipe = CytoolzRecipe()
```

But this time compilation with buildozer failed with Errot '[DEBUG]:    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/cytoolz/_version.py'
':

```
[DEBUG]:    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/cytoolz/_version.py'
```

I don't know what to do. I'm new to linux with colab.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new with kivy and buildozer. but i have some advice for you to resolve your probleme.

first if you have a problem when using colab, i mean if you get a error when you use buildozer in colab it means that you have a problem with the buildozer installation. and in this case copy the error from the log and copy it in chat-gpt or google bard because these ia will help you to better understand the error.

secondly if buildozer generate the apk file but when you install it and try to open the app, the app crach. you have to download android studio and all its requirement. then go in the android studio's terminal and enter the command 'adb logcat -s python'. this will show the error because of which your app crach, but before to see the error in the terminal you have to activate the usb debbug from your android phone. to do that go on youtube and research how to activate the usb  debuging in an android smart phone. I hope that it will help you